# how to make my variable visible from

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created inside of `viewDidLoad` the next view:

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((width-50)/2, (height-50)/2, 50, 50))
```

and set to it:

```
myView.alpha = 0
```

But I want to make it `myView.alpha = 1` when user tapped on `tableView cell`. But it does not visible from

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { ... }
```

How can I do it visible from there? Do not offer to create it, view, in XCode visually.

It prints the next error:

```
'ViewController' does not have a member named 'myView'
```

[image]

Comment: declare myView as global variable, above viewDidLoad!

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati I know, but look at pic that I just added to my question. Why it prints that `does not have a member myTableView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variable under your `@IBOutlet`s

```
var myView:UIView!
var width:CGFloat!
var height:CGFloat!
```

And in your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    width = mytableview.frame.size.width
    height = mytableview.frame.size.height
    myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((width-50)/2, (height-50)/2, 50, 50))
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
}
```

Comment: can we talk about it in chat? I want to discuss with you this

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the created  view into the main View

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake((width-50)/2, (height-50)/2, 50, 50))
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: of course I have added it. I just did not write it in my code. My problem is not it

Comment: are you trying to navigate to next view by creating it already and then making its alpha = 1 , instead of this approach i suggest you to make a new viewController add a segue and when the user taps the tableCell , make a segue to the next view . This is pretty sluggish